# How to reset the copper after removing vias in Altium Designer

Tags: altium, copper, copper-pour, gnd-pour

[image: Missing copper on the GND plane after removing vias.]

How do I reset the copper plane after removing vias and traces?

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: Looks like you already have your answer, but the keyboard shortcut T G A does the same as **T**ools -> Poly**G**on Pours -> Repour **A**ll

Answer (score 3):

In the toolbar select *Tools* then *Polygon Pours* and the *Repour All*

[image]

I also recommend changing your settings to "auto repour" by selecting system setup preferences (the cog in the top right corner) then *PCB Editor* then *General* then select the options under *Polygon Pours*

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

(In the PCB design view)

tools > Polygon pours > Repour all